# How to Assign Static IP Address to iPad?

Tags: ipad, wifi, network

I have been having a problem with the wifi connection on my iPad. After much research online, I have narrowed it down to an ip address lease renewal bug. The iPad drops connection when the ip address lease expires.

The suggested fix is to assign a static ip address for the iPad based on its MAC address and to enter the 'necessary values' in this screen on the iPad:
[image]

My question is: how do I assign a static ip to the iPad based on its MAC address? And how to I find out what these values are?

I know that I need to pick an ip address above the 'DHCP range', and I know what this range is. But I don't know how to tell the router to assign a static ip to the iPad and get the relevant numbers to fill in on the above screen. If it makes a difference, my router is a BT home hub 3.

I have very little knowledge of networking and would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: My thought would be that it has to be done at the other end.  For example, the router that assigns the IP address to the iPad.  I use AirPort Utility for this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to do the assigning via your Router. Normally by reserving an IP address within your IP range for a device. Using its MAC address.

*Without knowing what your Router Model is no one is going to be able to tell you in accurate detail. There is also the issue of being able to do this if you router is configured by your provider and if they give you the options to do this or by pass they standard idiot proof settings and go to Advance settings.

Please provide more info.*

To get you wifi Mac address from your iPad.

Go to Settings->General->About.

There you will see the Wi-Fi Address which is the MAC address.

[image]

Comment: Many home routers only issue a portion of the available IP addresses for their IP range through DHCP. If that is the case with your router you don't need to set up a reservation on the router, just assign one of the addresses that isn't handed out by DHCP.